# RestClient POST doesn't display status on header-only response

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest-client

I have a Rails action which responds with `head :ok`, rather than rendering any content. I'm calling this action using RestClient, like so:

```
resp = RestClient.post("#{api_server_url}/action/path", {:param_1 => thing, :param_2 => other_thing}, :authorization => auth)
```

The Rails server log shows that this worked as expected:

```
Completed 200 OK in 78ms (ActiveRecord: 21.3ms)
```

However, the resulting value of `resp` is the string `" "`, rather than an object I can examine (to see what its status code is, for instance).

I tried changing the action to use `head :created` instead, just to see if it produced a different result, but it's the same: `" "`.

How can I get the status code of this response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RestClient.post returns an instance of the class RestClient::Response that inherits from the String class.

You can still check the return code by calling the method code `resp.code`. Other methods are for example `resp.headers` and `resp.cookies`.

Comment: Ha, so it does. I feel very foolish for not thinking of that.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus Don't be. It feels like a bad solution to return the result as string when it actually contains more information (headers, cookies, status code).